# On the generation of linear groups

Tags: linear-algebra, classical-groups

$\def\GL{\operatorname{GL}}\def\id{\mathrm{id}}$Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a (commutative) field $k$. If $f:V\to V$ is a linear map I'll write $r_f$ and $V^f$ for the rank of the map $f-\id_V$ and for its kernel, respectively, say that $f$ is **one-dimensional** if $r_f=1$, and when that is the case call $f$ a **transvection** or a **dilatation** according to whether the determinant of~$f$ is $1$ or not. Jean Dieudonné proves in [Sur les générateurs des groupes classiques, Summa Brasil. Math. 3 (1955), 149-179] that the group $\GL(V)$ is generated by the set of transvections and dilatations. In fact, his *Théorème 1* there claims that

> the only linear maps $f:V\to V$ which cannot be written as a composition of $r_f-1$ transvections and a one-dimensional map are those which have $r_f>1$ and whose induced map $\overline f:V/V^f\to V/V^f$ is a homothecy, and the latter can be written as a composition of $r_f$ transvections and a one-dimensional map.

He also notes that a linear map $f:V\to V$ cannot be written as a composition of fewer than $r$ one-dimensional maps, so for maps which do not fall in the exceptional case described in the theorem the factorization he finds is minimal. On the other hand, if $f$ is a homothecy different from $\id_V$ then $r_f=\operatorname{dim}V$ and we can certainly write $f$ as a product of $r_f$ one-dimensional maps.

In their *The Classical Groups and K-Theory*, Alexander J. Hahn and O. Timothy O’Meara prove the same factorization result (Theorem 2.1.13 there, where they call a map **radial** if it is in the exceptional case of Dieudonné), and state a corollary (2.1.14) that among other things says that

> an element $f$ of $\GL(V)$ is igual to a product of $r_f$ one-dimensional maps and not fewer.

The «not fewer» parts is the same observation as the one made by Dieudonné.

> **Question:** Dieudonné's Théorème 1 and Hahn-O'Meara's Theorem 2.1.13 say that if $f$ is a radial map then the minimal integer $r$ such that $f$ can be written as a product of $r$ transvections and a one-dimensional map is $r_f$: how does one get from that to the claim in the corollary that they can be written as a product of $r_f$ one-dimensional maps?

Reading both texts leaves we wondering:

> **Question:** what does having a factorization of linear maps as products of transvections and one one-dimensional map get us, as opposed to a general factorization as a product of one-dimensional maps?

It may well be the case that the fact that the factorization they find is of that particular form simply because that's what is convenient — but maybe there is a use for that? For example, from the theorem and the corollary it follows that one does pay the price of one extra factor in the case of radial maps.

Comment: Both Dieudonné and Hahn—O'Meare actually work over possibly non-commutative fields, btw.

Comment: In [Can. J. Math., Vol. XXVI, No. 6, 1974, pp. 1412-1417] B. B. PHADKE shows that when the field is not commutative there are in SL(n,K) elements that are products of $r+2$ transvections but not of $r+1$. The theorems mentioned in the question imply that in the commutative case every element of SL(n,K) is a product of $r+1$ transvections (Dieudonné seems to write that this is also true in the non-commutative case)